# Python Unittest NoneType NameError

Tags: python, unit-testing, nonetype

I've searched through a load of NameError problems in unittest's on here but I can't seem to find anything relatable to my problem.

This is for a homework assignment so if you could just tell me where I'm going wrong and not how to correct it that'd be great. I'm trying to write a unittest for a function that swaps the last numbers in a list with the first numbers in a list.

Here is the code I have written for the function:

```
def swap_k(L, k):

    """ (list, int) -> NoneType

    Precondtion: 0 <= k <= len(L) // 2

    Swap the first k items of L with the last k items of L.

    >>> nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    >>> swap_k(nums, 2)
    >>> nums
    [5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2]
    >>> nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    >>> swap_k(nums, 3)
    >>> nums
    [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
    """

    L[:k], L[-k:] = L[-k:], L[:k]
```

This code works fine using a doctest, no errors at all so I'm pretty sure there's nothing wrong with it. However, the code I have written for the unittest keeps giving me a NameError. Here is the code for the unittest:

```
import a1
import unittest

class TestSwapK(unittest.TestCase):
    """ Test class for function a1.swap_k. """

    def test_swapk_1(self):
        """Swap the first k items of L with the last k items of L. Where L =
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] and k = 2."""

        L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        expected = [5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2]
        a1.swap_k(L, k)
        self.assertEqual(L, expected)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    unittest.main(exit=False)
```

And this is the error message:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_swapk_1 (__main__.TestSwapK)
Swap the first k items of L with the last k items of L. Where L =
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxxxxx\test_swap_k.py", line 13, in test_swapk_1
    a1.swap_k(L, k)
NameError: global name 'k' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.016s

FAILED (errors=1)`
```

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong, it's driving me crazy. Again if it's possible to tell me where I'm going wrong without telling me the answer please do so.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear: `k` isn't defined. In your doctest example, `k` was `3`:

```
a1.swap_k(L, k=3)
```

I'm just using `k=3` to be verbose. You can use `a1.swap_k(L, 3)` if you want.

Comment: I should have known I was missing something that simple, thanks for taking the time to answer. Very new to Python and never had a NameError before

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the variable k in your function.

Instead of:

```
a1.swap_k(L, k)
```

You probably meant to type:

```
a1.swap_k(L, 2)
```

or

```
k = 2
a1.swap_k(L, k)
```

or something similar.